# Change base branch of pull request

Tags: git, github

What is the effect of changing the base branch of your pull request say from master to another branch

Comment: not sure I understand the question, can you give more details about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The base branch is the branch you branched from. It's the branch your branch will be compared with and merged with.

From [About Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/)...

> Once a pull request is opened, you can discuss and review the potential changes with collaborators and add follow-up commits before ***your changes are merged into the base branch***.

Generally this is `master`. But occasionally you might be working off some other long running branch and need to indicate that as a base.

---

A situation when you might want to change the base branch is if you're stacking branches on top of one another. For example. Let's say you make a branch from master to implement a feature.

```
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature1]
```

You push feature1 and open a PR with its base as master. The PR will show your changes as D, E, and F.

While you're waiting for that PR, you write another feature that depends on the first one. You branch feature1 and do some more work in feature2.

```
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature1]
                   \
                    G - H - I [feature2]
```

You push feature2 and open another PR.

If you leave the base as master it will show your work as D, E, F, G, H, I. That's redundant with your previous PR. And it isn't clear that the feature2 PR is stacked on top of feature1. Someone might review feature2 before feature1.

So you set feature2's base to be feature1. Then feature2's PR will show only G, H, I and people can see from the base that it depends on feature1.